# 19" network rack shelf depth?

Tags: networking, rack

I am wishing to buy a network wallmount 19" rack, with a gross depth of 400mm.
How can I know in advance what is the maximum depth of a shelf and what should be the minimum free space between the end of the shelf and the rear side of the rack?
In my case the maximum device depth is 290mm

Comment: Ask the vendor?

Comment: Nice one! :-)... not so easy one of those chinese vendors... but I may try. Isn't there a "common rule". The rack is sold on Amazon BTW. And on Amazon 19" rack shelfs are sold in sizes 250, 350, 450, and 550mm. 350mm should be a proper depth, with 5cm of free space, however as there should be some space between the front glass and the front of the rack items, I have some doubts :-\

Comment: `How can I know in advance what is the maximum depth of a shelf and what should be the minimum free space between the end of the shelf and the rear side of the rack?` - Read the specifications?

Comment: There are no additional specs. It looks like really you have to ask the vendor, so there are no common rules for this....